# Resilient JSON.stringify that never throws

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a `JSON.stringify` wrapper that never throws exceptions, and also [includes properties like those on Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify).

I think this means it has to:

- handle cycles
- handle `BigInt`s
- catch exceptions thrown by a getter
- use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to find all properties, not just enumerable properties

I've had a go. I know `seen` is overkill and will remove duplicate objects, not just cyclical, but that's okay for my use case. The array detection will fire even if other properties have been set, causing them to be missed, which is undesirable. Wondering if there are any other issues I've overlooked?

```javascript
function stringifyResilient(value, space) {
    const seen = [];

    function replacer(_key, value) {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if ("toJSON" in value) {
                try {
                    value = value.toJSON();
                } catch {
                    value = null;
                }
            }
            if (seen.includes(value)) {
                return null;
            }
            seen.push(value);
            const len = value.length;
            if (typeof len === "number" && len >= 0 && Math.floor(len) === len && [...Array(len).keys()].every(i => i in value)) {
                const ret = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    let propValue = null;
                    try {
                        propValue = value[i];
                    } catch {}
                    ret.push(propValue);
                }
                value = ret;
            } else {
                const ret = {};
                Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).forEach(propName => {
                    let propValue = null;
                    try {
                        propValue = value[propName];
                    } catch {}
                    ret[propName] = propValue;
                });
                value = ret;
            }
        } else if (typeof value === "bigint") {
            value = value.toString();
        }
        return value;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space);
}
```